# Close Tab not working properly using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am working on MCV core with the Dapper project. On one of my pages, I have a Grid that contains records and ACTION,

No       Name       Address       Mobile         UPDATE       VIEW

1        XYZ        XYZ           123            UPDATE       VIEW

2        XYZ        XYZ           456            UPDATE       VIEW

When I click on the **UPDATE Link** from a specific row I am opening my new PAGE
**updareUserRecord.cshtml** **IN *NEW* TAB**.

When I click on **UPDATE BUTTON** after updating the record in **updareUserRecord.cshtml**, record gets updated. On the SAME page, I have **CLOSE** BUTTON. I want to close the **updareUserRecord.cshtml.**  Only.

Using Jquery and Javascript **I have tried but some times below code work sometimes not**. Can Anyone give me the perfect solution?

Like no matter, I want to close the PAGE.

This is the code I have tried.

```
@*<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnClose" onclick="javascript:window.open('','_self').close();">Close</button>*@
```

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnClose"  onclick="window.top.close();">Close</button>
```

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnClose"  onclick="window.close();">Close</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You can add simply click function using jQuery

$('#btnClose').click(function () {
  window.close(); //through writing this statement working also in browser 
  console
});

I think helps this solution Thank you :)
```